# Why does Wolfram Alpha state that $-\infty/0 = +\infty$?

Tags: calculus, infinity

I ran into a scenario when practicing L'Hôpital's rule which yielded -infinity/0. I broke this down into $-1 \cdot \infty \cdot \frac 1 0$, which I assumed equaled $-1\cdot\infty\cdot\infty$, which simplified to $-1\cdot\infty$ which equals negative infinity. So where did I go wrong with my logic as Wolfram Alpha [claims](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-infinity/0) the answer is positive infinity?

Here is the limit problem:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\ln(\cos x)}$$

Comment: It doesn't. It doesn't really work that way. What is the exact limit problem?

Comment: $\frac{1}{0}$ is NOT equal $\infty$. You cannot divide by zero.

Comment: l'Hôpital's rule does not apply, as Skylion indicated.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says -infinity/0 = infinity though...

Comment: I doubt that Wolfram Alpha says, word for word, that $-\infty/0=\infty$. That is your *interpretation* of what it ways.

Comment: @André Nicolas Please interpret it for me, I am not yet a trained mathematician after all. I will concede I don't know what the tilde means over the infinity sign in the result

Comment: @Skylion: Note that WA gives as result $\tilde{\infty}$. You would have to figure out what WA means by the "tilde" above the infinity sign.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha does not say that $-\infty/-0 = \infty$ exactly, it says that this is equal to *complex* infinity.  What's happening is that Wolfram Alpha is coming up with an interpretation for your inputs that makes the input sensible.  Specifically, you can't divide infinity by zero in the context of real or complex numbers, but you *can* do this in the context of the Riemann sphere, which is usually treated as the union of the complex numbers with a single point at $\infty$.

Comment: Beat me by few seconds :)

Comment: Hmm. @N.S., somehow I like Thomas' explanation and interpretation better. With complex logarithm we run into branch selection problems here. For example we could choose a branch of $\ln\cos z$ that approaches $2\pi i$ as $z\to0$. There's no way of making $\ln\sin z$ continuous in any punctured neighborhood of the origin, so I'm unhappy about treating this as a complex limit.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Did you check the wolfram alpha link in the question ;) ? The question and the Wolframalpha link are about $-\infty/0=\infty$ not about that particular limit ;)

Comment: Oh!? I didn't check that, sorry. Strange, but that does make your (and Aaron's) interpretation plausible.

Answer (score 4):

As has already been pointed out in the comments above, $-\infty / 0$ is not a well defined expression. We are not allowed to divide by $0$ and we als have to remember that $\infty$ is not a number. That said, you can still find the limit. In asking that, we are just interested in what happens to the values of $f(x) = \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(\cos(x))}$ when as $x$ *approaches* $0$.

First, I assume that $x$ is approaching $0$ from the right:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(\cos(x))}
$$

since when $x$ is close to $0$ and negative, then $\sin(x)$ is negative and then $\ln(\sin(x))$ isn't defined.

So as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, then $\sin(x)$ approaches $0$ from the right. Then $\ln(x)$ approaches $-\infty$.

Likewise, $\cos(x)$ approaches $1$ from the left, so $\ln(\cos(x))$ approaches $\ln(1) = 0$ from the left:
$$
\ln(\cos(x)) \to 0^- \quad\text{as}\quad x\to 0^+
$$

And here then is the crucial part. As $x$ gets closer and closer to $x$ while being positive, we have just nooted that $\ln(\cos(x)$ is negative while $\ln(\sin(x))$ is negative. So for values of $x$ very close to $0$ but positive, $f(x)$ is something negative divided by something negative, hence positive.

Also, the bottom is close to $0$ (small number) while the top is large (and negative). That makes the whole thing very large *and positive*

Therefore The whole limit is positive $\infty$.

---

If you want a precise proof and you are willing to accept that
$$
\ln(\sin(x)) \to -\infty \quad\text{as}\quad x\to 0^+
$$
and
$$
\ln(\cos(x)) \to 0^- \quad\text{as}\quad x\to 0^+
$$
then let $N>0$ be given. We want to find a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0<x<\delta$ then $f(x) > N$. Now pick a $\delta_1$ such that $\ln(\sin(x)) < -N$ when ever $0<x<\delta_1$.

Pick a $\delta_2$ such that $0 > \ln(\cos(x)) > -1$ whenever $0<x<\delta_2$. Then for $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$ you will have $f(x) > N$ for $0<x< \delta$.

Comment: Would you mathematically prove that though? I get it how you can estimate that the limit either through checking points or through the graph, but how would you prove that algebraically? Also why does Wolfram say -infinity/0 = + infinity?

Comment: @Skylion: You want an $\epsilon-\delta$ type of proof?

Comment: I don't care too much about the limit, I just want to know why Wolfram is evaluating -infinity/0 as +infinity

Comment: @Skylion: I tried to explain things a bit better. If you want something different, you might have to go to the definition of a limit.

Comment: To clarify. You have (although, as noted not completely correct) -infinity/-0 (or in other words in the denominator you are getting close to zero from the negative side of the axis)... But I hate to say it this way since is not correct. You cannot write a division by zero. Only when you are considering the limit it makes sense...

Comment: @Thomas was not for you :-) was for the OP

Comment: But how is Wolfram generating it's answer though? What is it assuming that I am asking?

Comment: This is a good answer @Skylion you should care, it is not evaluating what you think it is. Limits are not substitutions.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score -2):

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}{\ln\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)
              \over
              \ln\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)}
=
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}{\ln\left(x\right)
              \over
              \ln\left(1 - x^{2}/2\right)}
=
2\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}{1 \over x^{2}}\,\left[-\ln\left(x\right)\right]
=
{\large +\,\infty}
$$

Comment: You should at least give some justification for the sawn-off Taylor-series substitution.

Comment: @AlexR It's quite obvious: Just divide and multiply and you get some "1" limits. I imagine the OP and everybody else knows that.

Comment: Still you silently use the properties of $\ln$ AND the two Taylor series. Not that obvious to the OP I guess when looking at the question itself.

Comment: Is it obvious? I'm assuming we're not allowed to use L'Hospital's rule. [To prove $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(x)}=1$, see this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708542/lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-lnx-ln-sin-x-without-lh%c3%b4pitals-rule) To prove $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(\cos (x))}{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=1$, where I used $x\to 0$ instead of $x\to 0^+$ because $\cos (x)$, $\frac{x^2}{2}$ are both even functions, I've tried a few of the methods given in the link I gave, and none of them worked.

Comment: To make it short, notice that $$\frac{\ln\left((\cos (x)) / \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right)}{\ln \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}\to \frac{0}{0^{-}}$$

has limit value $0$, but it gives an indeterminate form (notice Taylor series for $\cos x$), so we can't immediately know if the limit is equal to $0$. This is one method used in an answer.

Comment: Also, look at the series that WolframAlpha finds for $\ln\left((\cos x) / \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right)$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+ln((cos+x)%2F(1-((x%5E2)%2F2. We can't immediately find, e. g., $\frac{x^{4}}{24\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}$, because it gives an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. This is another method used in an answer.

Comment: [See this question for how to prove $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(\cos (x))}{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)} = 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2442078/prove-lim-x-to-0-frac-ln-cos-x-ln-left1-fracx22-right-1-witho)