# Prove $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=1$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

> Prove that:$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=1$$
>
> without L'Hopital's rule.

I don't know if this is possible.

[WolframAlpha agrees with this limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+(ln(cos+x)%2Fln(1-(x%5E2)%2F2))+as+x+to+0).

There's a similar limit without L'Hopital's rule $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\ln (x)}=1$, [which is easier to prove and some proofs can be seen in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708542/lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-lnx-ln-sin-x-without-lh%c3%b4pitals-rule).

In $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\ln (x)}=1$ you can see $x\to 0^+$, which is important, but in this case $\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}$ is an even function and we can use $x\to 0$.

I've tried some of the methods given in the linked question and none of them worked.

[I first saw this problem in this answer, where I also discussed the methods I've tried to solve this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/524965/263326)

We could use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}=1$.

---

Edit: I've noticed that also

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos (\cos x)}{\cos\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=1$$

[See WolframAlpha here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+(cos(cos+x))%2F+(cos+(1-(x%5E2)%2F2))+as+x+-%3E+0)

And also $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (\cos x)}{\sin\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=1$$

[See WolframAlpha here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+(sin(cos+x))%2F+(sin+(1-(x%5E2)%2F2))+as+x+-%3E+0)

And also

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan (\cos x)}{\tan\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=1$$

[See WolframAlpha here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+(tan(cos+x))%2F+(tan(1-(x%5E2)%2F2))+as+x+-%3E+0).

And also $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arcsin(\cos x)}{\arcsin\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=1$$

[See WolframAlpha here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+(arcsin(cos+x))%2F+(arcsin(1-(x%5E2)%2F2))+as+x+-%3E+0)

Etc.

Comment: All your limits after the fold (horizontal line) are trivial because putting $x=0$ does not create any problem. Same is the case with $(\cos x) /(1-(x^{2}/2))$. What is needed here are the limits $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x} {x^{2}}=\frac{1}{2},\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. This gives an answer similar to Michael Rozenberg's. You could've posted this as an answer. I won't put the answer here to let you do it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Using $\ln(1-y)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^n/n$ we get
immediately $\ln(1-x^2/2)=-x^2/2+O(x^4)$, and also, after observing
that $\cos x=1-x^2/2+O(x^4)$, $\ln\cos x=-x^2/2+O(x^4)$. Therefore
$$\frac{\ln \cos x}{\ln(1-x^2/2)}=1+O(x^2).$$

Comment: You used $1-\cos x=x^2/2+O(x^4)$, $\ln(\cos x)=\ln(1-(1-\cos x))$, etc. You could use series division algorithm (similar to long division of polynomials) to find the series of $\frac{1}{\ln(1-x^2/2)}$ ($1=1+0x+0x^2+\cdots$) and then use Cauchy product to find the product of the series of $\ln(\cos x)$ and $\frac{1}{\ln(1-x^2/2)}$. I understand it.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{\ln{\cos{x}}}{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}=\frac{\ln(1+\cos{x}-1)}{\cos{x}-1}\cdot\frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}}{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x^2}{4}}\rightarrow1.$$

Comment: Much better than my solution, +1 and I will delete my answer.

Comment: Simple answer without any sophisticated tools. +1

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You can use the expansions to get the result

Answer (score 1):

On OP's request I am converting my comment into an answer. The limit in question is easily solved if one rewrites the given expression as $$\frac{\log(1+\cos x-1)} {\cos x - 1}\cdot\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{x^{2}}{(-x^{2}/2)}\cdot\frac{(-x^{2}/2)}{\log(1-x^{2}/2)}$$ And then the limit is easily seen to be $1\cdot(-1/2)\cdot(-2)\cdot 1=1$.

Other limits in your question (after the fold) don't have any problem as we can just plug $x=0$ to evaluate them (the functions concerned are continuous at $0$).

Comment: A note: you could've also written $\frac{1-\cos x}{\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}$, which tends to $1$ as $x\to 0$, instead of $\frac{\cos x-1}{x^{2}}\cdot \frac{x^{2}}{(-x^{2}/2)}$.